# "Well" trained model of an Autoencoder NN does not match with predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I’m using Keras API for training an 5-layers autoencoder with the following building:

- 84 input/ouput units
- 3 hidden layers, with [40,30,40] units respectively
- Dropout regularization in each hidden layers, with [0.25, 0.30, 0.25]
  of decay respectively

I have a training dataset with a shape (355,84), being 355 samples, a validation dataset with a shape of (117,84), and a test dataset with a shape of (117,84). During the first attempts, the implemented activation functions were “relu” & “lineal” (no activation), and after fitting the model and plotting the training and validation loss, it resulted in a high-variance scenario, with great difference between both errors after 60 epochs. As expected, with linear activation, the training data overfit the model, while any prediction output with samples of validation/test dataset ended up being far different from the input.

Therefore, after a little of research I changed the “linear” activation function by “tanh”, with two added factors, upon trial and error, of 5.0 and 1.5 (this is, activation = 5.0*tanh(x/1.5) ) in order to achieve a behavior that, with an overall look, it seemed that both training and validation cost converge with low-bias after 60 epochs. The following image shows that:

[Training and validation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyt25.png)

However, the problem remains the same: the training data overfit the model, and the predictions are as deviated as the previous attempt. The next image refers to a single sample taken from both training and validation datasets. In general, the prediction from training dataset performs very well, not being the same on the validation one:

[Train Entry vs Prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWbaN.png)

[Val. Entry vs Prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD1f1.png)

With respect to the dataset, I made sure these were the cleanest possible, thus maintaining a close correlation. I’ve already tried with the hyperparameters adjusts, but none of then diminished the problem in the least:

- Dropout decay value changes, in a range between [0.20, 0.40]
- Nodes quantity changes, in the first and third hidden layer, in a
  range between [40-60]
- Nodes quantity changes in the middle layer, in a range between
  [30-50]
- “tanh” factor changes: the former being in a range
  between [1.0-8.0] and the latter with [1.0-3.0]

Here is the code, with all of the implemented libraries being updated to the last versions:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, optimizers, regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

'''
x_train.shape: (355, 84)
x_val.shape: (117, 84)
x_train.shape: (117, 84)

'''

# Hidden-layer nodes quantity: 
encoding_dim_1 = 40 
encoding_dim_central = 30 
encoding_dim_2 = 40 

# Factors of CustomFunction
y_factor = 5.0
x_factor = 1.5

# Custom Function
CustomFunction = lambda x: y_factor*K.tanh(x/x_factor)

# L2 regularization parameter (NOTE: ACTUALLY IS SET TO 0, SO IT IS NOT BEING IMPLEMENTED)
reg_parameter = 0.0

################################################################################

# Input layer
input_layer = layers.Input(sample_shape, name='Input_layer')

# Hidden layers
layer_1 = layers.Dense(encoding_dim_1, activation = CustomFunction, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg_parameter), name='First_middle_layer')(input_layer)
dropout_1 = layers.Dropout(0.25)(layer_1)
layer_2 = layers.Dense(encoding_dim_central, activation = CustomFunction, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg_parameter), name='Central_layer')(dropout_1)
dropout_2 = layers.Dropout(0.30)(layer_2)
layer_3 = layers.Dense(encoding_dim_2, activation = CustomFunction, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg_parameter), name='Last_middle_layer')(dropout_2)
dropout_3 = layers.Dropout(0.25)(layer_3)
ouput_layer = layers.Dense(*sample_shape, activation = CustomFunction, name='Output_layer')(dropout_3)

# Construct model
model = Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = ouput_layer, name = 'Autoencoder_Model')

################################################################################


# Add training parameters to model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss=['mse'])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(x_train,
                   x_train,
                   epochs=60,
                   batch_size=40,
                   validation_data = (x_val, x_val),
                   verbose=0)

################################################################################
# Plot results
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(loss, 'bo', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(val_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print(f"Last training loss value reached:   {loss[-1]}")
print(f"Last validation loss value reached: {val_loss[-1]}")

################################################################################

# Prediction from validation set

# Prediction of a single sample upon selecting it randomly from the training dataset
x_entry_train = x_train[np.random.randint(0,high=x_train.shape[0]) , :].reshape((1,x_train.shape[1]))
prediction_train = model.predict(x_entry_train)

plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(x_entry_train[0,:], '-b',label='Training Entry')
plt.plot(prediction_train[0,:], '--r',label='Training Prediction')    
plt.plot([0,int(x_entry_train.shape[1])],[0,0], '-k', linewidth = 1)
plt.title("Train Entry vs Prediction")
plt.xlabel('Points')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


# Prediction of a single sample upon selecting it randomly from the validation dataset
x_entry_val = x_val[np.random.randint(0,high=x_val.shape[0]) , :].reshape((1,x_val.shape[1]))
prediction_val = model.predict(x_entry_val)

plt.figure(2, figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(x_entry_val[0,:], '-b',label='Validation Entry')
plt.plot(prediction_val[0,:], '--r',label='Validation Prediction')    
plt.plot([0,int(x_entry_val.shape[1])],[0,0], '-k', linewidth = 1)
plt.title("Val. Entry vs Prediction")
plt.xlabel('Points')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Also, the entire train/validation/test dataset can be found in this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TfRCEI-LRJ6X3y9LAamq8hWXszPGIRHX?usp=sharing)

Maybe it is due to inappropriate selection of the activation function. What do you think? I would appreciate any recommendations that could solve the current problem, and if you have any questions feel free to ask, I will listen and answer everything you have in mind. Thanks in advance!

- List item

Comment: Its just overfitting, which is not really on-topic here in Stack Overflow

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm aware its overfitting, but it is strange that may be the case because of the close distance between both validation and training errors. I look for any non-redundant explanation that could minimize the problem, because I've tested many ways you can found easily on internet, and none of then have worked pretty well.